# XML Schema issue

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

So I`m trying to build a web service to validate a XML from a Schema. My problem is the following : 
When I use this XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Creat la data 5/13/2007 2:15:00 PM-->
<ListaCase xmlns="ListHNS-schema">
<Casa strada="florilor">
 <nr>Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts</nr>
<cod>The Beatles</cod>
<oras>Teora</oras>
<tara>1967</tara>
 </Casa>
 <Casa strada="teilor">
<nr>Dark Side Of The Moon</nr>
<cod>Pink Floyd</cod>
<oras>Corint</oras>
<tara>1973</tara>
```

against this schema :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"      version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsd:element name="ListaCase">
 <xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="Casa">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="nr" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="cod" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="oras" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="tara" type="xsd:int" />
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="strada" type="xsd:string" />
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
   </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
 </xsd:schema>
```

My Visual Studio says he can`t find the schema. But when I use another schema and another XML everything works. Does anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema 
attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
elementFormDefault="qualified"      
version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsd:element name="ListaCase">
 <xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="Casa" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="nr" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="cod" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="oras" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="tara" type="xsd:int" />
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="strada" type="xsd:string" />
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
   </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
 </xsd:schema>
```

Please note the  `maxOccurs="unbounded"` attribute on

```
<xsd:element name="Casa">
```

Comment: happy to see it solved your problem, basically it specifies that you can have unlimited number of <Casa> as children of <ListaCase>, default is 1, while you had 2 <Casa> within <ListaCase>. Also you can have minOccurs which specifies the minimum occurance, default for  minOccurs is also 1, so a <ListaCase> without <Casa> will be invalid, you may want to set minOccurs="0" as well to allow zero occurance of <Casa> inside <ListaCase>

Answer (score 1):

Might be because of the different XML character encodings? First is UTF8, second is UTF16.

Comment: this schema was generated using this website [link](http://www.xmlforasp.net/codebank/system_xml_schema/buildschema/buildxmlschema.aspx) . Should I change the encoding to UTF8?